# Externally target (URL) and expand accordions, having difficulty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really new to JS, and am trying to teach myself in order to get some external linking set up on some HTML pages I'm currently working on. On clicking a URL like below, I'd like the page to automatically scan down to the accordion and expand it.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to click a URL such as: 
    http://www.example.com/page#test2

and have the page scroll down and expand the 'test2' accordion. Is this doable?

```
<div class="accordion-group">
<h2 class="pane-title"><span style="color:#000000;"><a id="test1">test 1</span></a></h2>
<div class="pane-content">
<p>Lorum ipsum asdghjfds asdghfgd asdghsgasd</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-group">
<h2 class="pane-title"><span style="color:#000000;"><a id="test2">test 2</span></a></h2>
<div class="pane-content">
<p>Lorum ipsum asdghjfds asdghfgd asdghsgasd</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm playing around with some JS like below, but not having much success. As a beginner, any advice on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var getHash = location.hash; //get hash from js object location

    function activateAccordion (id) 
    {
        if(id.length)//check if hash isn't empty
        {
            var accordion = $('a[href="' + id + '"]');
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: accordion.parents('.panel').offset().top 
                //scroll to accordion
        }, 500,function(){
            accordion.click(); //simulate click
        });
    }
};

activateAccordion(getHash);

});
</script>
```

Comment: can you add a snippet ? or something like that ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5694bmws/ - hopefully this helps!

Comment: This doesn’t work very well in a fiddle environment, we have no chance to actually call the result page with a hash in the URL in there ... Add debug outputs (console.log()) to see what your script actually does ... does it pick up the right id value, does it actually find the element you are looking for, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i just posted a totally different solution, Seeing miss understood your question.

Anyway when you read the hash from the location it will return something like `#test1` with the hashtag character so you need to remove it with something like this

`var hash = location.hash.split("#")[1]` and run your code.

Now the scrolling of the page will override the animation of the animate function

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this, but it still doesn't seem to be making much of a difference page-wise - it's scrolling down, but it's not expanding the accordion. Is tagging the ID as <a id="test1">test 1</span></a> enough to link a url that would end in '#test1', or does this need to be tagged in a different section (such as in the div tags?)

Comment: what do you mean by expanding ? for your other question the page will scroll when you pass it the id of any element it doesn't have to be an `<a>` tag

Comment: Ah - I'd ideally like it to be that when a user clicks a URL with a tag at the end of it, that they are directed to the page, the page scrolls down and the accordion is collapsed so they can read the content in the <p> tags - does that make sense (and is it possible?)

Comment: I think you're looking for some CSS3 animation if you want to expand the text